# How function overload resoultion takes place in C++?

Tags: c++, function, overloading

I am a beginner in C++. I wanted to know, how internally the function overloading takes place in C++

Comment: The specification for how overload resolution works in C++ is 30 pages long and is tightly coupled to many other parts of the language (name lookup, template instantiation and specialization, dependent names).  A complete explanation of overload resolution would require a book.  A partial explanation (either a high-level explanation or an explanation of a small piece of overload resolution) is likely to be subtly incorrect.

Comment: I think that this is a bit vague. What in particular would you like to know? Implementation details (for _which_ implementation)? Or language semantics (we could be here all week)?

Comment: The best high-level overview of this subject can be found in Appendix B of _[C++ Templates -- The Complete Guide](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/)_, which condenses the basics of overload resolution into a very readable 10 pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you reading [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201721481). This concept is explained in depth.

On a higher level, function overloading is allowed if  both the functions

- have same name
- declared in the same scope
- have different parameter list.

---

On the lower-level ( inside how compiler figures it out),  here's how it is done.

There are 3 steps for function overloading resolution.

```
e.g void f();   
    void f(int);
    void f(double, double = 3.4);
    void f(char *, char *);

    Function call inside main -> void f(5.6);
```

1. Identifies the set of overloaded functions considered for the call, they are called as candidate functions. A candidate function is a function with the same name as the function that is called & for which declaration is visible at the point of call.
   It also identifies the properties of the argument list in the function call, i.e no of arguments and their types.

   **Selected : All 4 functions with name 'f'**
2. Selects the function from the set of candidate functions found in step 1 that can be called with arguments specified in the call. Those are called as viable functions.
   A viable function is a function that has the same nof of parameters or more parameters ( addn paramters has an associated default argument) than the arguments in the actual function call. Types of arguments must be convertible for the function to be classified as viable.

   **Selected : void f(int) and void (double, double =3.4)**
3. Identifies the best viable function among the all viable functions.
   For (int) conversion need to apply which is a standard conversion (double to int). But for (double, double=3.4), there's a exact match, so no conversion needed. No conversion is better than a conversion.

   **Selected : void (double, double = 3.4 )**

Comment: I think the OP was asking about how the compiler knows which version of the function is being called

Comment: .. and have the same return type

Comment: The last point (have the same return type) is not necessary -- overloaded functions may have different return types.  The return type itself has no impact on the overload resolution; only the argument types matter.

Comment: And of course, the last step is the scariest, because there are just so many rules between integer promotion and conversions rules, and the ranking that occurs between them :/

Comment: In fatc, having a _different_ return type is not just allowed, it's probably the most common. E.g. `float sin(float); double sin(double)` or `T operator+(T,T)` for many types T.

Answer (score 3):

It takes place internally with mangled names.

For the file

```
void blah(int f)
{
}

void blah(double f)
{}
```

I get the symbols

```
ethan@EthanPc ~ % nm blah.o   
0000000000000009 T _Z4blahd
0000000000000000 T _Z4blahi
```

Notice the d for double, and the i for integer.

Comment: This is one common solution, but it isn't the only one.

Comment: I'd even argue that this is how function overloading works _externally_, on disk, whereas the question was how it worked _internally_. The compiler is likely to have a symbol table internally which holds the unmangled name and type; mangled names are there just for the linker.